# Checking my understanding about function return

Tags: c++, function

As a newbie, I found it quite cryptic about the explanation of returning from function in C++ books.

Here is a summary of my understanding, hopefully someone can correct it:

Premises:

```
T foo() {
   ...
   return expr;
}

main() {
   T var = foo();
}
```

Is my below understanding about the returning process correct?

1. The evaluation result of `expr` is implicitly converted to declared function return type `T`. This conversion happens **within** foo();
2. The converted value above is used to initialize a temporary object, say "x". Sub-Question: Does this second conversion happen within foo() or main()?
3. The temporary object "x" is used to initialize variable `var` within main().

Any input is welcome!

Comment: "*Does this second conversion happen within foo() or main()?*" What could the difference possibly be? Are you concerned about whether locals in the function are guaranteed to still exist during the conversion?

Comment: There are many influencing variables to your questions (e.g., copy elision, move semantics etc.)

Comment: you didn't specify, but modern/C++11 compilers will optimize out temporary/move/copy type operations using "return value optimization" which you can find lots of info on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Just trying to understand the process.

Comment: Is T just a placeholder, or is T a template?

Comment: The returned object is created before local variables are destroyed. That's a sensible question, all in all, since this is a fairly important point.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit, T is a type, say "int", or maybe "string &"

Comment: @KerrekSB, Do you mean the temp obj "x" (in the context) by saying "the returned object"?

Comment: Conversion will only happen if it needs to (int -> double, etc) and if it can. Your question is kind of vague.

Comment: @rabbitholedigger Note `string &` or just `string` makes a **big** difference regarding the behavior. Your question is quite unspecific and broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's approach this systematically.

If a function is declared as `T f();`, and `T` is not `void`, and if the function returns normally, then it must return via a statement of the form `return e;`, where `e` is some expression.

When you evaluate the function-call expression `f()`, you obtain a value. Suppose `U` denotes an object type. If `T = U &` or `T = U &&`, then the value is of type `U`, the expression `e` must be able to bind to the reference, and the return value *is* the value of `e`. (The return value is also a so-called "glvalue", in terms of its value category). Nothing else happens in this case. The value of the function call is the thing being returned.

However, when `T = U`, then the value of `f()` is a so-called "prvalue" (a "pure rvalue"), and this necessitates the construction of a *temporary object* of type `U`. This object is constructed as if by `U obj = e` (i.e. implicitly converted from the `e`). The value of `f()` is then this temporary object. It may either be used to initialize yet another object (e.g. `U x = f();`), or it may be bound to a reference (e.g. `U && r = f();`).

The binding of the return expression `e` to the function-call value happens as the last thing inside the function body scope. Notably, this is *before* the end of the scope, i.e. before scope-local objects are destroyed. For example, if an exception is thrown during the construction of the return value object, scope unwinding has to happen to destroy local objects before the exception passes to the calling scope. Another useful illustration may be in the use of scoped guards, e.g. mutex locks:

```
U f()
{
    std::locK_guard<std::mutex> lock(state_mutex);
    return state.get_value();
}
```

Here we assume that the initialization `U obj = state.get_value();` makes sense, and we assume further that `state.get_value()` must only be called while `state_mutex` is locked. The above code does this correctly and concisely.

Comment: Indeed great answer. Addressed the entire concern in the question in a way that also explains the value category (which I am actually struggling with, too).

Answer (score 4):

1. You are correct, the implicit conversion happens within `foo`. Consider when you have more than one `return` statement and each one returns a different type - all of those types must be converted before a value can be returned.
2. There's no second conversion. The first conversion occurs as part of the construction or assignment of the temporary.
3. Correct, except as explained below.

There's an optimization that many compilers will make called [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which skips the temporary altogether.

Comment: This answer covered all the concerns. Voted up!

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is essentially correct. 
There can be some optimizations, so that there are not that many steps of 
copying. This can be either in the form of `return value optimization` or 
in c++11 `move semantics`

Regarding your sub question; 
You should make **neither** assumption, in say custom conversion operators, constructors 
destructors, etc.